# How to deploy Elastic Search cluster consisting of multiple hosts using ES docker image?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I want to deploy ES cluster consisting of different hosts using ES docker image. I came across some material on this, and was able to deploy ES cluster on same host using docker compose. However, I am not able to use docker compose to deploy ES cluster consisting of different hosts.
I have used following links for reference - 
https://www.elastic.co/blog/docker-networking
https://stefanprodan.com/2016/elasticsearch-cluster-with-docker/
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multi-elasticsearch-docker-containers-per-host/49989

Following is my docker run command that I am using on each host. ES gets started on each host, but hosts are not able to join existing cluster, even if I am using discovery.zen.ping.unicast.host.

On node - 1 (with ip - 10.91.104.52), I start container with following command.

```
sudo docker run -p 9200:9200 \
- e "network.publish_host = 10.91.104.52" \
- e "cluster.name = mycluster" \
- e "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts = 10.91.104.52,10.91.104.120" \
- e "dicovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1"
```

On node- 2 (with ip - 10.91.104.120)

```
sudo docker run -p 9200:9200 \
- e "network.publish_host = 10.91.104.120" \
- e "cluster.name = mycluster" \
- e "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts = 10.91.104.52,10.91.104.120" \
- e "dicovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1"
```

On each of the node, ES gets started. But when I access http://host:port/_cluster/health, I see a cluster with only one node on each of the host.

Is there any issue with above docker command or do I require to use Docker swarm with overlay network?

Comment: I think you should bind 9300:9300 port as well (used for cluster communication). You should also check that Elasticsearch binds to the appropriate network interface (by default it's 127.0.0.1), publish_host is not enough. Finally give your Elasticsearch logs.

Comment: Hi Nikhil Bhide, you dit it?

Comment: I got it! thank you